# EWS c#: error while trying to use EWS to read emails for outlook I am getting the error "autodiscover service couldn't be located"

Tags: c#, console-application, exchangewebservices, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a windows form to read emails from outlook with specific subject using EWS. My script is working in my machine when i use the code:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("my email address", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

in the EWS code. But on executing it on another machine with different user.

I get an error:

> Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Can anyone help me how to fix this error so that I can run on any machines with different user accounts?

Comment: because they have to use their email and not your email.

Comment: also, please show some code. we can't read your mind